# Failed to resolve: com.github.jblough:Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library:v1.0

Tags: android, dependencies

I want to install the following library in my project.
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/348#!package

I have added the jar file in build folder 
I also added the dependencies which are mentioned there. 
I also added :

```
enter code here
  maven   { 
             url "https://jitpack.io"
      }
```

[image]

But I found this error:

[image]

Please! help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do u just want a pdf viewer library?

Comment: Yes!  i want to add pdf viewer library

Comment: where did u added the maven url? in app level build.gradle or in project level?

Comment: i have added this in both places

Comment: you didn't follow `To get this project into your build` instruction. Why? That is fine that it doesn't work if you do it not the right way.

Comment: Dear If you got it plz guide me. I will follow your instructions and I will do accordingly plz tell me thanks

Comment: any helping material will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this library in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

here's the [link](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) of the library just try it

Comment: but  i need only the following 
library!
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/348#!package
for using my project

Answer (score 0):

I just added code in build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    mavenCentral()
}
```

}